# How to center an image inside a tbody tag (that also has a thead)?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Column 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Column 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://material.io/icons/static/images/icons-180x180.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

tbody {
  background: red;
}

tbody td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

As you can see, the image isn't centered in the table (but a little on the left):

[image]

How do I achieve this?

[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/vWvmLd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```html
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <img src="https://material.io/icons/static/images/icons-180x180.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

The `colspan="2"` tells the `<td>` to take up two cells wide. This allows the one `<td>` to take up the area of the two `<th>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Add colspan="2" to the

```
<td colspan="2">
        <img src="https://material.io/icons/static/images/icons-180x180.png">
      </td>
```